# Short Code for dot with assignment operator

Tags: java, assignment-operator

I have have a case to replace only one string in an array.
So I am using

```
namAryVar.get(namAryVar.size() - 1).namVar =
                namAryVar.get(namAryVar.size() - 1).namVar.replace("]", " ");
```

To do Addition we have += operator

```
numVar = numVar + 10;
```

Can be written in short as

```
numVar += 10;
```

Similarly, Is there any dot and Assignment operator .

```
namAryVar.get(namAryVar.size() - 1).namVar .= replace("]", " ");
```

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: short answer `no`.`replace` is a function whereas `+` is an operator.

Comment: No, but you can avoid duplication and make the code a bit cleaner by assigning `namAryVar.get(namAryVar.size() - 1)` to a variable first.

Comment: Creating a variable increase the num of lines of code and wastes memory so

Comment: replace is a function I agree. But Dot is a operator to joning class with function right. So I think there must be a short code.

Comment: there is not  dot is an instance operator shortcut in java

Comment: Your primary goal should be optimizing the readability of the code, not obsfucating it by avoiding to use variables.

Comment: Increasing the number of lines is not a problem.  It's often the case that the changes we make to make code more readable also increase the number of lines (e.g. breaking a large method up into smaller methods increases the number of lines, because we need to declare the new methods and call them, but it makes the code easier to read).

Comment: Also, memory shouldn't be a concern.  It should be a small local variable which means it will be on the stack and disappear as soon as the method returns, or maybe earlier with a good optimizer.

Comment: "Dot" is not an operator in Java.  All the binary operators are listed starting at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.  The "assignment operators" are listed in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.  You could make a case that you can think of "dot" as an operator, and it might be useful in some ways to think of it like that.  But that's not how the language sees it.  If you want to propose a new syntax for your kind of shortcut, there are ways to do that.